# Notification on iscsi/multipath failure

Tags: centos, iscsi, multipath

I'm running iscsi-initiator combined with multipathd on a CentOS machine. How can I effectively be notified (e.g. via email) when one of the paths goes down?
I can't find any suitable option on multipathd or iscsi configuration.

I somehow stumbled on this [Multipath Monitor](https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/cool_tools/multipath-monitor/) script but it's not good for me because I need to be aware of the problem exactly as it happens.